# goexpect, fastest way to check if telnet is open

Tags: go

I'm using goexpect for connection to multiple wi-fi access points.
For some of them I need to use telnet, and SSH for others.

So, I need fastest way to check if telnet is open for some IP.

Code now looks like

```
e, _, err := expect.Spawn(fmt.Sprintf("telnet %s", ip), -1)
res, _, err := e.Expect(userRE, timeout) // we expect user prompt
    if err != nil {
        // if timeout, pass control to code block which handle SSH connection
    }
```

I suppose there is a better and faster way to tell if telnet is open.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after getting the github.com/reiver/go-telnet package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/reiver/go-telnet"
)

func main() {
    address := "127.0.0.1:8080"
    _, err := telnet.DialTo(address)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("Telnet closed")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Telnet open")
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for answer. Yes, I saw this package, but what interesting for me in this example is how can i optimize response time using goexpect, to be exact what timeout should i set as parameter to Spawn method. or maybe I can tell that telnet is closed from some field of result object *GExpect